# ios-App crashes unexpectedly when re Enters to the app

Tags: ios

When I enter the app it is working fine but when I re-enter the app it will not shown the particular page or starting page of the app but it is again displaying the Launcher image and **crashes** and after crash again it is working fine.

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0]; 
UILocalNotification *locationNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey]; 
if (locationNotification) { 
    // Set icon badge number to zero 
    NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@",locationNotification); 
} 
return YES;
```

please give the solution I am new bee to `iOS`.

Comment: whats in your `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

Comment: What the error message?

Comment: We are not the `Magician` show the error logs if possible someone must help you and its `iOS` not ios.

Comment: Remove the app .then  clean, build & Run the app.

Comment: Guys - he's a new bee - beehive yourselves.

Comment: [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];

    UILocalNotification *locationNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

  
    if (locationNotification) {
        // Set icon badge number to zero
        NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@",locationNotification);

    }

 
    return YES;

Comment: @Anupama Put that in your question, formatted.  Nobody wants to read a comment full of code.

Comment: There is no error message. just display Launcher image in simulator no action is performed..In phone the app is crashed

Comment: @Anupama Once, I came across this issue . Just remove the app from device. clean & build.

Comment: What code you have implemented ApplicationDidEnterBackgroung and ApplicationWillEnterForeground ? Haven't you implemented any perform selector or Notification

Comment: @Ohnomycoco Everyone is behaving themselves they are asking for the relevant information to help solve there problem.

Comment: I clean and build the app kumar but it is same problem

Comment: Gee Popeye - way to miss the joke.

Comment: In applicationDidEnterBackground I created a thread and call the methods

Comment: Sleeping on the main thread is very very bad idea.

Comment: is there any other idea

Comment: @Anupma- I hope the thread you created in applicationDidEnterBackground and calling methods are creating the issue please apply break points and let us know

Comment: @Ohnomycoco How is that a joke? You are being rude by insinuating something or you were being serious in telling everyone to behave. I see no way that could be taken as a joke.

Comment: @Ashutosh Mishra yes the problem in calling the method..Thank you for your solution

Comment: @Anupma No prob if you want I will write the solution you can accept it if you want ?

Comment: UILocalNotification is part of UIKit. You shall never call UIKit methods on anything else than the main thread.

Comment: @iEinstein  yes pls give me the solution

Comment: @Anupma- So you haven't found the solution of your problem?

Comment: No.please help me out

Comment: When you know that the methods you are calling in background then you should be able to imagine how to use them without creating problem? Otherwise give me code I will check it

Comment: Congrates! Ok if you got the solution can I write my answer?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46421/discussion-between-anupama-and-ieinstein)

Answer (score 1):

Anupma

From seeing the problem which is described here  I suspect some methods or notifications are calling in `applicationDidEnterBackground`. Please check it and if it is you can find the solution to solve it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you want you can choose it as a solution or choose your answer as a solution will make this question closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

        [self Backgroundmethods];



        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            //your code to update UI if any goes here



        });

    });

  }
```

I worte the all my background methods in seperate method and calling that method with in applicationdidEnterbackground  in seperate thread.